# Floating 2 Elements in Unsigned List Side by Side

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, css-float

Floating 2 Elements in Unsigned List Side by Side is not working.

.widget_gdstarrating_star div {
    float: right;
}

Comment: How the stars are included, what tag?

Comment: I am not very good with Wordpress but in the GD Star Rating Template, it is just <div>%STARS%</div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when you remove the child selector `>`

```
.widget_gdstarrating_star div {
    float: right;
}
```

I guess, you have the class `widget_gdstarrating_star` at the `ul` and then `div` is not a child of `ul` but the `li`.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9zJP/)

*Update:*

The above solution does not work for fractional ratings, i.e. 3.5 or 4.1 stars. This is because of the nested `div`s holding the background and the rating. Therefore it is better to keep the child selector, but insert a `li` to select only the outer `div`

```
.widget_gdstarrating_star li > div {
    float: right;
}
```

With this selector the rating is floated to the right side, but the yellow stars are flush left and the alignment problem is gone.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWfCu/1/)

Comment: Can you verify that these are really two divs? Have you tried with Firefox DOM inspector for example?

Comment: It seems the width of the yellow stars must be a multiple of `16px`. In the four stars case the width is only `60.8px`. When you increase that to `4 * 16 = 64px`, you get a proper alignment. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWfCu/)

Comment: @BrettPowell After some sleep, I got a better solution. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you put up a jsfiddle and we can just fix it there? With a width at 100%, what's the actual UL's width? It may be too small...